# AzCosmosDBSqlContainer : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: azure, powershell, object, reference, azure-cosmosdb

I am using AzCosmosDBSqlContainer to check details of a CosmosDB (SQL api) container in PowerShell; I am getting this error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

However `Get-AzCosmosDBAccount` and `Get-AzCosmosDBSqlDatabase` commands are working fine.

Can someone help me with this?

Command used:

```
$ResourceGroup="MyResourceGroup"
$CDBAccountName="mycosmosaccount"
$dbname="myDatabase"
$containername="MyContainer"

$cosmosaccount=Get-AzCosmosDBAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $CDBAccountName 

$cosmosdbname=Get-AzCosmosDBSqlDatabase -AccountName $cosmosaccount.Name -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup  -Name $dbname

Get-AzCosmosDBSqlContainer -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -AccountName $cosmosaccount.Name -DatabaseName $cosmosdbname.Name -Name $containername
```

Comment: I believe this is a known issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/11381.

Comment: You are right @GauravMantri , i had posted this question on that forum as well, and i got the below update and workaround

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround after getting an update from Microsoft team.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/11381

This issue is going to be fixed in upcoming version of Az.CosmosDB 0.1.4

**Workaround:**

> ```
> Replace "my***Name" with your own values
> $resourceGroupName = "myResourceGroupName"
> $accountName = "myAccountName"
> $databaseName = "mYDatabaseName"
> $containerName = "myContainerName"
>
>
> $apiVersion = "2020-03-01"
> $databaseResourceName = $accountName + "/" + $databaseName
> $containerResourceName = $databaseResourceName + "/" + $containerName
> $containerResourceType = "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers"
>
>
> Write-Host "List containers in the database"
> Get-AzResource -ResourceType $containerResourceType -ApiVersion $apiVersion 
> -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $databaseResourceName
>
> Write-Host "Show specified container"
> Get-AzResource -ResourceType $containerResourceType -ApiVersion $apiVersion
> -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $containerResourceName
> ```